# Ruby: Gsub - multiple string replacements in a single line [in an array]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

is there a way to replace multiple strings in a single line of array using gsub.

here is the log file

```
13:29:00 (alex) OUT: "72500_2010_0F" abcd@S400532  
13:31:12 (alex) IN: "72600_2010_0F" abnc@S403818
13:31:52 (alex) IN: "71200_2010_0F" osa@S400583
```

I would like to replace the below

```
(alex) with "" 
OUT:  with OUT
IN: with IN
"72500_2010_0F" with XYZ
"71200_2010_0F" with QWE
"72600_2010_0F" with UIO
```

The original file (log file) is put into array and I wanted to read each line in the array and perform gsub. Dont want to use Hash as its lil complicated -As being Ruby Beginner...& to Regex...

```
array1.each do |element|
  i = element.gsub(/?????????/) [ What should go here]
  array2.push(i)
end
```

I dint want to make changes to original array but push the modified lines into different array i.e array2

What is the best & easy to understand code to do this? - Please help

Comment: Why not use file operations to read the file, read every line, replace the content of line with whatever you want and write the new line to a new file ?

Comment: How do we do that? - I'm loading file into an array and reading each line array and changing its contents one by one... may be not so good approach yeah?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [String#sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) it seems there are many ways to do what you want:

1. One approach can be to use a hash as second parameter

   ```
   def cleansed_log_line(line)
     replacement_rules = {
       'alex' => '',
       'OUT: ' => 'OUT ',
       'IN: ' => 'IN '
     }
     matcher = /#{replacement_rules.keys.join('|')}/

     line.gsub(matcher, replacement_rules)
   end
   ```
2. Another approach can be to to use block form

   ```
   def cleansed_log_line(line)
     replacement_rules = {
       'alex' => '',
       'OUT: ' => 'OUT ',
       'IN: ' => 'IN '
     }
     matcher = /#{replacement_rules.keys.join('|')}/

     line.gsub(matcher) do |match|
       replacement_rules[match] || match
     end
   end
   ```
3. Another not so good implementation

   ```
   def cleansed_log_line(line)
     replacement_rules = {
       /alex/ => '',
       'OUT: ' => 'OUT ',
       'IN: ' => 'IN '
     }

     replacement_rules.each do |match, replacement|
       line = line.gsub(match, replacement)
     end

     line
   end
   ```

Hashes and RegEx are nothing to worry about. This function can cleanse any line passed to it and would return a cleansed line.

Comment: hi, like your 1st approach - and is easy to understand. I'm guessing, line.gsub(matcher, replace...) will look into each key in a line and replace this with 'key value'  is that right? Thanks for your hlep mate...